# Issue with curly brackets in beamer - why?

Tags: beamer, syntax

I am struggling with a macro which auto-generates some frames in beamer. While doing so I came across a situation I do not fully understand. My pedagogical examples boils down to the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\frame{Works}
\frame\begingroup Barks-why? \endgroup
\frame\bgroup Barks-why? \egroup
\end{document}
```

Why do the second and third frame bark at me claiming a syntax problem?

I would be grateful for some thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When used in the command form, `\frame` accepts the entire contents of the argument as the content that will be set within the frame. This argument is defined as the *braced group* or *token* immediately following `\frame`. In your case, the *tokens* that are causing the issue opens a group that is not properly closed.

- In the first case - `\frame{Works}` - this would be `Works`. No problem.
- In the second/third cases - `\frame\begingroup ...`/`\frame\bgroup ...` this would be `\begingroup`/`\bgroup`. These are set inside a frame (which is scoped itself) and not properly closed with `\endgroup`/`\egroup`.

That's why you see an error pointing to a "forgotten `\engroup`":

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\endbeamer@frameslide ...amer@framepauses}\egroup 
                                                  \ifx \beamer@frametitle \@...
l.8 \frame\begingroup
                      Barks-why? \endgroup
```

Comment: Ahhhhh. :-) Yes. Of course. Thank you. Makes sense. I tend to forget the fine line in TeX distinguishing lexical and syntactical levels. Still searching for a document which describes this clearly and precisely and concisely.

Answer (score 1):

To me it's been helpful to remind myself the reason they exist:
You want things like

```
\def\beginmyenviron{ABC \bgroup abc}
\def\closemyenviron{xyz \egroup XYZ}
```

so you can control local variables more freely.
In this case, you don't want `\bgroup` to be interpreted
exactly as a `{` character or otherwise
the first definition will never end.

And then things kind-of stuck here.
You cannot come up with a definition where `\something` in

```
\def\beginmyenviron{ABC \something abc}
```

is not treated as a `{` character when being defined,
but treated as a `{` character when being used.
You can, for instance, try `\edef`,
but `\edef` doesn't turn `\bgroup` into `{`.

So to answer your original question,
the safe play is to use `\begin{frame}` and `\end{frame}`
to build up your macros.

If you really hate `\begin` and `\end`,
an alternative is to use a holder-macro.

```
\def\content{First sentence.}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\content\expandafter{\content second sentence.}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\content\expandafter{\content third sentence.}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\content\expandafter{\content fourth sentence.}
and then finally
\frame{\content}
```